# How to show that an unbounded set does not exist using the axioms of ZF Set Theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, set-theory, axioms, separation-axioms

I am currently studying a course on [ZF Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) and would like to know how to show that a set does not exist using the axioms.

For example, the following two sets are clearly equivalent to a set of all sets (and so cannot exist), however, I am unsure how to prove this rigorously using the axioms to show that such sets cannot exist:

$$\{x : \exists y (x \in y) \} \space \text{and} \space \{x : \exists y (x = y) \}$$

My intuition says that this is a result of [The Axiom of Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification). This states that for a WFF (well formed formula) $\phi$, we have the following relation:

$$ \forall a_1 ...\forall a_n \forall z \exists y\forall x ((x \in y) \leftrightarrow (x \in z) \land \phi(a_1...a_n))$$

In other words, this states that every property specifies subsets of a particular set. In  the case of the two examples above $\phi$ would be $\exists y (x \in y)$ or $\exists y (x = y)$ respectively.

Clearly, some bounding set is needed in the two examples that I provide above in order for these to be valid sets, although I am struggling to make this argument rigorous and would be grateful for any guidance in producing a stronger argument to show that these sets cannot exist under the axioms of ZF Set Theory.

Comment: The trouble is that you write a couple of expressions which are meaningless: they don't, as you realise, build sets.  So I think you've got to write this differently. Eg "Is there a set $\Omega$ such that $\Omega$ contains every set which is a member of some set?" Now you can write a proof that every set is a member of $\Omega$ and then you're done.

Comment: Suppose the set of all sets existed, use seperation to construct the set of all sets that do not contain themselves, and using russels paradox get a contradiction.

Comment: I know how to get a contradiction to show that the set of all sets cannot exist. However, I want to formally show that the specific sets in my question cannot exist. If I start the proof by saying that these are both equivalent to the set of all sets, then I think that's missing a key part of the proof @ancientmathematician

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment, I think the problem here is that we cannot assume that the sets in the question are equal to the "set of all sets" without proper justification @Shinrin-Yoku

Comment: Since it's easy to prove that for any set $x$ we have $x\in\{x\}$ it is trivial to prove that every set is a member of my putative $\Omega$.

Comment: For every $x$, we have that $x \in \{ x \}$, whose existence follows from axioms. Thus, we have that $z=z \leftrightarrow \exists y (z \in y)$.

Comment: Why is this sufficient to disprove the existence of such a set @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: So, for an arbitrary set $x$, we know that $x \in \{x \}$. Therefore, the set $\Omega$ contains every set $x$ since $x$ is unconstrained and will always be a member of a set. Therefore, $\Omega$ is the set of all sets. Is this along the lines of what you were thinking @ancientmathematician ?

Comment: I thought that was what I said.

Comment: I was just clarifying that I was understanding your argument correctly. What is the axiomatic justification that for all sets $x$ there exists a set $\{ x \}$ such that $x \in \{ x \}$? Of course this is trivial, however, I am trying to write out a formal proof and would like to justify each step @ancientmathematician

Comment: I think there's a pairing axiom that produces a set $\{a,b\}$ whose elements are precisely $a$ and $b$. Apply it with $a=b=x$ to get a set $\{x,x\}$ whose elements are precisely $x$. We usually write $\{x,x\}$ as just $\{x\}$.

Comment: Thank you. If you want to write that up, I'll accept this as the answer. Otherwise, I'm happy to type it up. @ancientmathematician

Comment: I think that you can self-answer, I'm not absolutely sure exactly which axioms you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a general algorithm for proving something is not a set. One approach is using a proof by contradiction. Assume it is a set, and derive a contradiction.

**Remark:* The Class $V = \{x \space| \space x = x\}$ is not a set. Note: We would call V a Proper Class.*

> **Corollary:** $∀x∃y(y∉x)$ ( Otherwise such a set would be V)

---

I will prove the following claim:  "$\{x \space |\space \exists y(x∈y)\}$ is not a set."

**Proof by Contradiction:**

Assume $A = \{x\space |\space ∃y(x∈y) \}$ is a set (so that we can elicit a contradiction). By Corollary we can find some set $x_0$∉A.

By the Pairing Axiom, since $x_0$ is a set we have that:

$$y = \{x_0,x_0\} = \{x_0\} \space \text{is a set} $$

So, $x_0 \in y$. Thus, the existence of $y$ means that $x_0 \in A$. This is a contradiction as we picked $x_0$ so that it is not in $A$.

---

*Note$_1$: The proof for showing that $\{x \space | \space ∃y(x=y)\}$ is not a set is very similar (Hint: instead of using the Axiom of Pairing, use the Axiom of Extentionality).*

*Note$_2$: Your intuition about the Axiom of Separation is correct, you could use it directly. The proof would be a more complicated version of using Separation to prove $V$ is a not set.*

Comment: If I am remembering correctly, your corollary follows from Extensionality + Separation. Is this correct? @MichaelCarey

Comment: Also, depending on the formulation of the Pairing Axiom, you may need Pairing + Separation to ensure y = {x} exists. As some formulations of Paring don't ensure the the only elements of y are x. With seperation you take a subset of such y, such that its only element is x.

Comment: Yes. The proof for the Corollary I had in mind, was Proof by Contradiction: Assume a set A exists which contains every set. As every set is equal to itself (by Extentionality) A contains every set equal to itself. By seperation we show the Russel Class exists. Contradiction. @FD_bfa