# Using theorem to prove a collection $\left \{ x:\phi (x) \right \}$ is not set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As I was reading Set Theory: A First Course, I encountered a theorem in the page 31 that allows to prove if a given class  $\left \{ x:\phi (x) \right \}$ is a set. It goes as follows:

> **Theorem 2.1.3** *Let $\phi (x)$  be a formula. Suppose that there is a set $A$ such that for all $x$, if $\phi (x)$, then  $x\in A$. Then there is a unique set $D$ such that for all $x$, $x\in D$ if and only if $\phi (x)$.*
>
> *In other words, the class $\left \{ x:\phi (x) \right \}$ is, in fact, equal to the set $D$.*

Which can be written as:

$$ \exists A \space \forall x \space (\phi (x) \implies x\in A) \implies \exists! D \space \forall x \space (x \in D \iff \phi (x))$$

If my understanding is not wrong, this theorem talks about the fact that if a set $x$ satisfies the formula $ \phi (x)$, then there already exists a set $A$ for which $x$ belongs, but it also implies that all the elements of $A$ do not necessarily satisfy $ \phi (x)$. Hence when we want to prove that a certain collection $\left \{ x:\phi (x) \right \}$ is a set, we must find that set $A$ which contains all those elements $x$ that satisfy $ \phi (x)$.

In the book page 37, there is this exercise:

> Prove the collection $\left \{ x: \exists y \space (x \in y) \right \}$ is not a set.

Normally when we want to prove something does not exist in **ZFC**, we assume its existence and then derive a contradiction. Thus if is not a set then it must be a proper class. So is it correct to say that when we do this we are actually saying that $A = \left \{ x: \exists y \space (x \in y) \right \}$ in terms of the theorem?

Comment: Your question is not totally clear to me, but I think the answer is no. Like you said, we want to assume that $\{x : \exists y (x \in y)\}$ is a set, and derive a contradiction -- this doesn't need to have anything to do with the theorem you stated. Indeed, that theorem can be used to show that a class *is* a set, but cannot be used (directly) to show that a class is not a set.

Comment: Usually, to show that a class is not a set, we want to show that it is "too large". What is your intuition here -- why is the class $\{x : \exists y (x \in y)\}$ "too large" to be a set?

Comment: In your first comment you talk about the fact that it can't be used to prove directly that a class is not a set, so you mean it can be proved by contrapositive proof? Assuming the existence of $D$ and then deriving a contradiciton so we can conclude that $A$ does not exist.

Comment: In regards to your second question, i think that it is too large because in fact every set belongs to its powerset.

Comment: Note, $A$ does not depend on $x.$ When you wrote "If my understanding is not wrong..." then wrote something that seems to mean $A$ depends on $x.$ But you need one set $A$ that works for all $x$with $\phi(x)$ true, $x\in A.$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648970/how-to-show-that-an-unbounded-set-does-not-exist-using-the-axioms-of-zf-set-theo) very similar post.

Comment: We know that in formal set theory, it is not true that for every formula $\phi$ there is the set $D$ of all and only those elements that satisfy $\phi$ (see Russell's paradox).

Comment: The above Theorem allows us to prove that such $D$ exists, because we have an already existent set $A$ to which we can apply Separation. Uniqueness follows from Extensionality. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652799/how-to-prove-uniqueness-with-uniqueness-quantification-uniqueness-of-the-axiom/4653078#4653078).